# Define specific internet routing with Network Manager

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, ethernet

I have a wireless internet that goes out to the Internet, but I have Ethernet set up for a private internal non-Internet-facing network.

When I connect my Ethernet on this private static configuration, I lose Internet access as it tries to use Ethernet as the route.

Is there a way to manually specify that the default route for internet traffic should be via the wifi instead of via the ethernet?

NOTE: This is on a Laptop - it uses MULTIPLE Wireless networks with DIFFERENT IPs/Gateways.  Setting the default gateway by hand on the command line is not feasible for this setup.  It is also unfeasible because I sometimes VPN my data over my home VPN connection when off-site.

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://serverfault.com/questions/589673/changing-the-default-gateway-multiple-nics

Comment: I think I would add static routes to the internal services and set the default gw (used for unknown ip's) to the wireless gateway

Comment: As @ElderGeek implies, I doubt you can do this with Network Manager, but rather use /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: @chili555 that breaks DHCP and the settings for multiple wifi networks in NetworkManager in a GUI setup.  If it's not possible, then we need to yell at Ubuntu for failing in this regard.

Comment: @ElderGeek Impossible when you are using multiple wifi networks as one might in a laptop - hence the question here

Comment: @ThomasW. My apologies for the confusion. Perhaps you could edit your question and change "a wireless network" to "multiple wireless networks" to provide more clarity. Thank you!

Comment: @ElderGeek done

Comment: Thinking outside the box, If there's something I don't wish to do by hand, I usually develop a script for it.

Comment: @ElderGeek Perhaps a wider range question: Is there a way with command line tools and network manager negotiating the connection parameters (DHCP, etc.) to define the ethernet interface for the default route?  (The other consideration is, I use VPN sometimes, so... adds to the complication)

Comment: @ThomasW. Not sure I understand how /etc/network/interfaces breaks DHCP. You can certainly specify _iface wlan0 inet dhcp_.

Comment: @chili555 it breaks Network Manager handling of the connection - in which different wifi networks I have different DNS servers

Comment: I see, it breaks NM but not DHCP, then.